# Simple Android App Not Responding

Tags: java, android

The application works fine until I assign an Id to the button, then it starts becoming unresponsive. The code is minimum, but I encountered the same thing in another small test project.
 The problem is I don't understand why it doesn't work, and especially how to fix it, even after all the internet search I did.
I just started Android basics, so I apologize if the error seems too simple. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

### Main class :

```
public class Test extends Activity 
{
/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test);
    m.setOnClickListener
      (
      new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
        public void onClick(View v) 
          {
                    // some code
          }
        }
      );
    }
}
```

And here is the main.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:text="asdas"
></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `android:layout_width & height` attributes to button aswell, I'm not sure if you can compile the way you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks. In the previous project, I had all the layout width and height attributes, but didn't worked when rebuilding it (seems I have to clean & rebuild in netbeans). Due to this, I assumed that they can be left aside. Thanks !.. That helped me a lot.

Comment: never used netbeans, im eclipse guy :) anyway glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

At least `android:layout_width` and `android:layout:height` are missing, so the button cannot show. What you could do is use the graphical layout editor provided by the android sdk for Eclipse, add a button from there and then watch how the xml has been built to fully understand all parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifiy the width and height of the button.

Example:

```
<Button 
    android:text="Click"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
</Button>
```

Where dp (dip) is density indepedent pixel: [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android)

Without these attributes, the application compiles, but ends with the error:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo... You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```